# d3 event object after drag

Tags: javascript

I'm working on some code that resizes objects with drag and I can't seem to make the following true: `d3.event.dx === d3.event.dy ===1`.  Is it possible to infer diagonal draw intent from one drag event?

Comment: You need to separate conditions with an *and* (`&&`) and: `d3.event.dx === 1 && d3.event.dy === 1`.

Comment: ah.  thanks +1. i was thinking maybe d3 drag events couldn't change in both directions in one event.

Comment: can you explain why the above is always false?

Comment: It's always false because it will evaluate d3.event.dx === d3.event.dy first. The result will be either true or false, which it will then compare with 1. So you're effectively evaluating either "true === 1" or "false === 1" both of which are false.